# subfiles: can't find citations in main file but in subfiles with TeXstudio

Tags: citing, subfiles

I can not print the references in my main.tex.
However, there is no problem in the subfiles.
Editor: TexStudio, on macOS/ubuntu and mactex/texlive 2019

I followed this approaches: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=10320 but none of them work correctly.

Here my minimal code

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[compress]{cite}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\def\biblio{\bibliographystyle{../customestyle}\bibliography{../library}}}
\begin{document}
\def\biblio{}

\subfile{/chapter_1/chapter_1}


\bibliographystyle{customestyle}
\bibliography{library
\end{document}
```

And then the subfile in a subfolder

```
%!TeX root = chapter_1
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
...
\biblio
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a curly bracket missing after `\bibliography{library`

Comment: Can you make the code into a compilable document that allows people to reproduce the problem? The missing documentclass and the ... in the preamble will through errors and the custom bib style is not available

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error was actually in an included file not shown in the posting, and the OP solved the problem himself. His self-answer is unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo, turns out I accidentally put a normal

```
\bibliographystyle{customestyle}
\bibliography{library}
```

call in one of the subfiles. Now everything works!
(sorry, am a stressed PhD student like I guess nearly everybody here)